# Firebase Token: What is the Bearer?

Tags: php, laravel, firebase-authentication, jwt, lumen

I'm using this reference repository for testing out authentication with firebase token inside Lumen:
https://github.com/alinnert/lumen-auth-reference

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this part in the instructions:

```
GET /secret
  Header:
    Authorization: "Bearer ...token..."
```

I'm using RESTClient (www.restclient.net) to stimulate my Lumen Backend with http requests. 
There, I can define custom headers, which probably is what I need to do here. 
So I did this, I've set the name inputfield to "authorization", and it already offered me autocompletion so I guess this was right. 
Then I move to the attribute value field and type in

Bearer...token...

Now when I send the request I get the following response:

```
UnexpectedValueException in JWT.php line 79: Wrong number of segments

    in JWT.php line 79
    at JWT::decode('Bearer...token...', 'pawifjopawiejfpoaiwejfpoji', array('HS256')) in AuthServiceProvider.php line 36
    at AuthServiceProvider->App\Providers\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in RequestGuard.php line 54
    at RequestGuard->user() in GuardHelpers.php line 49
    at RequestGuard->check() in GuardHelpers.php line 59
    at RequestGuard->guest() in Authenticate.php line 38
    at Authenticate->handle(object(Request), object(Closure)) in Pipeline.php line 148
    at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
    at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 32
    at Pipeline->Laravel\Lumen\Routing\{closure}(object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 102
    at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in RoutesRequests.php line 780
    at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array('App\\Http\\Middleware\\Authenticate'), object(Closure)) in RoutesRequests.php line 626
    at Application->handleFoundRoute(array(true, array('middleware' => array('auth'), 'uses' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\SecretController@index'), array())) in RoutesRequests.php line 528
    at Application->Laravel\Lumen\Concerns\{closure}() in RoutesRequests.php line 783
    at Application->sendThroughPipeline(array(), object(Closure)) in RoutesRequests.php line 534
    at Application->dispatch(null) in RoutesRequests.php line 475
    at Application->run() in index.php line 28
```

I don't know if I just did the syntax wrong or if I need to provide actual data where the periods are.
So instead of

Bearer...Token...

somehting like

Bearer:  Token:

For those who want to try out for themselves:
In "SecretController.php", you need to change the code to:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

//use Illuminate\Http\Request;


use App\User;
use Firebase\JWT\JWT;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Response;


class SecretController extends Controller
{
  public function index(Request $request)
  {
    return new Response('Hello ' . $request->user()->name,
      200, ['Content-Type', 'text/plain']);
  }

  public function pub()
  {
    return new Response('Hello World', 200, ['Content-Type', 'text/plain']);

  }
}
```

Otherwise you can't use the get routes defined in the web.php

Comment: put the token (the real access token, not the word "token") into the authorization header, e.g `Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxMjM0NTY3ODkwIiwibmFtZSI6IkpvaG4gRG9lIiwiaWF0IjoxNTE2MjM5MDIyfQ.SflKxwRJSMeKKF2QT4fwpMeJf36POk6yJV_adQssw5c`

Comment: Baam, you just saved my day, thanks! :)

Comment: glad to help :-)